# Swift Custom TabBar Controller: stop the animation of the initial load layout

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I've just started playing around with iOS, so assume little knowledge. We're using xibs, not storyboard, and a custom tabbar. When we switch to the new nav controller and associated view with

```
self.addChildViewController(viewController)
viewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
self.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
selectedViewController = viewController
```

the first time we do this, there is an animation that occurs to fill in the navbar (comes from left side) and the view (comes from above). The second time there isn't an animation. Is there anyway that I can skip the animation that occurs in the initial load?

I assume the viewDidLoad has some default animation built on to explain this if the view was not initialized yet. I initially thought I could just call this method on my nav controllers when I create them at the beginning of the app like so

```
  UINavigationController(rootViewController: AMRLoginViewController())
```

And then iterate through them calling viewDidLoad.

But that ran into errors related to delegates and optional values being set to nil.

Comment: viewDidLoad is a delegate method called by the system. It's never a good idea to call that yourself. That animation doesn't sound like any system animation I know of.

Comment: if it isn't a system animation what is it? I've actually run into it several times while poking at iOS where when a view is loaded all of its elements will run in from somewhere off screen. Only using this custom menu view implementation tho.

Comment: Right. I'm speaking about "the navbar (comes from left side) and the view (comes from above)" I can't think of a system animation where the view "comes from above." Did you write all of the view controllers you're using. Do they have any custom animations? Do you know of any apps where you see this animation in conjunction with changing tabs in a UITabBar? There is no default animation from changing selected view controller in a UITabBarController.

Comment: Just looked back and there was a point in the code when it wasn't doing this bizarre crap. Gonna hunt it down and report back.

Comment: found the commit; a coworker had placed self.view.layoutIfNeeded within a transition accidentally rather than calling it on the menuView. If you want to move your comment concerning it definitely not being a default transition + the issue being a self.view.layoutIfNeeded within an animation cycle to an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewDidLoad is a delegate method called by the system. It's never a good idea to call that yourself. That animation doesn't sound like any system animation I know of.

I would look at the UIViewController's lifecycle methods viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and check if frames or constraints are being changed within an animation block.